# Is this one question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, asking-questions

My post was put on-hold because a person claimed it was asking multiple questions.  I reframed the post as [Generating shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243476)

Does the new post qualify as just asking one question?

Can I have this evaluated and the question taken off hold soon?

Comment: The question under discussion has been deleted by the Roomba ([auto-deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006))

Answer (score 4):

Your question is in the Reopen review queue, so it will be evaluated by the community as to whether it should be reopened or not.  The community may disagree with me (I see there are already a couple of reopen votes), however **I don't believe it is specific/narrow enough yet**.  It's not necessarily that it's multiple questions, but that the question is too broad.

> What would be the best approach to create a shapefile for the simulation: by coding a program, using an editor, or adapting an existing dataset?

Asking for a "best approach" is very broad - any or all of these could be the correct answer, and many factors regarding your setup, your data, your experience would need to be considered to actually determine which one is right.

The [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) tells you to

> Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

So instead of asking which method would be best, decide on one and give it a go and come back with a specific problem if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3):

When posted on Main I voted to place that question on hold as too broad for similar reasons to why, even after your edits, I still think that is the case.

For me to vote for it to be re-opened I think you need to address this paragraph that appears to have been shoe-horned into a single sentence/question:

> What would be the comparative advantages and disadvantages to creating
>   a shapefile for the simulation given a continuum of the amount of
>   information to be displayed from small to large: by coding a program,
>   using an editor, or adapting an existing dataset?

Asking the community to list the advantages and disadvantages of anything would make a question too broad in its own right but here you seem be asking three concatenated questions which are each too broad:

1. What would be the advantages and disadvantages to creating a shapefile for the simulation given a continuum of the amount of information to be displayed from small to large by *coding a program*?
2. What would be the advantages and disadvantages to creating a shapefile for the simulation given a continuum of the amount of information to be displayed from small to large by *using an editor*?
3. What would be the advantages and disadvantages to creating a shapefile for the simulation given a continuum of the amount of information to be displayed from small to large by *adapting an existing dataset*?

I think your post distils to presenting an idea, suggesting three approaches to trying to explore it, and asking the community to analyse each.  That would be fine to ask in the [GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) which is designed for discussion and sharing of experiences.

I think you should choose an approach, commence a proof of its concept, and if it does not just work then you could ask on Main about where you are stuck with that.

If potential answerers think that you have gone off track with the single approach that you ask that question on, I have confidence that they will say so, and suggest an alternative approach where you might have more success.

Comment: I disagree.  You are reading the question wrong.  I am asking to compare and contrast three methods.  That is different than asking for the best approach.  That is different from asking three different questions -- it is one question.  What you are saying is that asking questions of a general type like "what are the relative advantages and disadvantages of using milk, butter, or water in recipe X?"   The key term is "relative" -- it makes for one question.  If this works for the culinary arts, it should work for GIS too.

Comment: @user9885 I think your culinary example is too broad for precisely the same reasons that I outlined here for GIS.  If X is a milk shake, then you testing one, two or three of your three options would most likely eliminate the need to ask the culinary community so that its volunteered time could be used to answer focussed questions.

Comment: Why should I test one, two, or three of three options if someone has done the work already?  Isn't the purpose of a forum is avoid reinventing the wheel if someone knows the answer already?  Is nobody know the answer, then all means I will test it on my own.

Comment: @user9885 You really should take the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce every user to this **focussed Q&A site** because it is *NOT designed to work like a discussion forum*.  If you do not wish to test, then the need for you to ask a focused question seems to be particularly in your own interest.